# Error in posting data to Rest API server with auth Token in android

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to post data to REST API server with retrofit + RxJava . When I am trying to send data to server , it said " HTTP 500 Internal Server Error Occurred". But when the data is send with POSTMAN, it succeeded.

This is the function for sending data in Model.

```
 // Encountering with 500 server error
fun postSchedule(data : ScheduleResponse , errorLD: MutableLiveData<String>){

    Log.d("POST DATA", "${data.title} ${data.remindMeAt}" )
    userClient.postScheduleItem(data)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(object  : io.reactivex.Observer<ServerResponse>{
            override fun onComplete() {

            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

            }

            override fun onNext(t: ServerResponse) {
                errorLD.value = t.status
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                errorLD.value = e.message
            }
        })
}
```

This is my API interface

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@POST("schedules")
fun postScheduleItem(@Body data: ScheduleResponse): Observable<ServerResponse>
```

This is the retrofit client.
 val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

```
var dbInstance: TodoDB = TodoDB.getInstance(context)

var rxJavaAdapter = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())
val retrofitBuilder =
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJavaAdapter)

fun <T> createService(serviceClass: Class<T>, authToken: String?): T {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        val interceptor = AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken!!)
        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor)
            retrofitBuilder.client(httpClient.build())

        }
    }

    return retrofitBuilder.build().create(serviceClass)
}
```

Please help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Client side code is not enough to determine what causes the server to respond with 500. The best you can do is start debugging the issue.

There are several directions you can go:

1. If you have access to the server or know someone who does, you could debug the server and determine what causes the Internal server error. Maybe the server logs can help as well and you don't have to actually step through the server code.
2. If you don't have access to the server, you could look at the body of the server response. Maybe there's a detailed error description there in html, json or some other format that will help you find out the root cause.
3. If the above steps don't help then it's very useful that you know the request works with POSTMAN. You can compare the exact POSTMAN request with the exact Retrofit request, header by header, 
   line by line. To do that, you should first add your `httpLoggingInterceptor` to your okhttp client builder with

   ```
   val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
   ```

   and look for the request log in logcat.
   If you spot the differences between the working and the not working requests, then you should work your way through all the differences, and adjust the retrofit request by adding or modifying headers using okhttp interceptors so that, at the end, the retrofit request looks exactly the same as the POSTMAN request. I suggest you remove the `AuthenticationInterceptor` at first and simulate it "manually" with a custom interceptor and a hard coded auth token.

Retry the request every time you eliminate a difference to isolate the cause of the internal server error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes,I did and it was solved. The problem is in sending json back to the server, the server is not accepting the id , so I excluded it. Thanks for the answer Mr.Janos...